# Kayako API Library Get all tickets (including closed status)

Tags: php

I am using KAYAKO API library to integrate resolve with my system. I want to get all the tickets from the kayako resolve ***including closed tickets***. Currently i am using

```
$resolve_department = kyDepartment::getAll();
$resolve_tickets = kyTicket::getAll($resolve_department);
```

All tickets except closed are responded in the resultset. While there should be all (including closed tickets).

I am following `http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DEV/PHP+API+Library` as a guide.

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

```
$resolve_tickets = kyTicket::getAll(kyDepartment::getAll(), kyStatus::getAll());
```

Comment: Its been long when I dealt with kyoka.. Cant test the solution now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to include parameter "statusid=1,2,3" (3 is for closed)
it will returns all tickets.